# One Signal linking is not working in React Native - Expo App

Tags: react-native, expo, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

Despite using react-native v 0.72+ where they said 0.60+ have auto linking it isn't working in my local.

Am getting the following error : Could not load RNOneSignal native module. Make sure native dependencies are properly linked.

NB: I have never linked something like this in React Native, am a react.js developer trying our Native, please help me as fresher

I did everything as said in the documentation